# Part of Linear Layout hide under Action bar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I know this may be a stupid question, however as a newbie i cant get to work around it.

So i want to add actionBar with Back Navigation Button and part of LinearLayout is hidden. How could i solve the problem ??

[image: LinearLayout hidden By ActionBar]

**Code**

**MainActivity.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Content Layout**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    >


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_productname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="15"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Product Name"
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Price"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <!--Add Product-->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Product"
        android:onClick="addProduct"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Expectation**

I manually set margin-top to lower Linearlayout and show the expected result.

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Since you are using CoordinatorLayout you need to use layout_behaviour, layout_anchor and layout_anchorGravity to properly align the layout. Just add the following line in your include:

```
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

So it will be like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the layout behaviour to your content

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```